# How to combine functions so they're more generalized

Tags: python

I've made a code that can throw die, count the outcomes and decide the winner, i've done this for 6 different cases for an assignment for school, but after I got it back I want to make it shorter. Its just 6 different functions now that all take just one set of data.

By data I mean these inputs:

```
 Case 1: 
 S1 = (9, {1,2,3,4}, lambda x: 1/4)
 S2 = (6, {1,2,3,4,5,6}, lambda x: 1/6)

 Case 2:
 S1 = (1, set(range(1,36+1)), lambda x: 1/36)
 S2 = (36, {0,1}, lambda x: 1/2)

Case 3:    
S1 = (6, {1,2,3,4}, lambda x: 1/4)
S2 = (4, {1,2,3,4,5,6}, lambda x: 1/6)
```

I put these cases inside this code;

```
def Case1(Rolls):
    Win = 0
    S1 = (9, {1, 2, 3, 4}, lambda x: 1 / 4)
    S2 = (6, {1,2,3,4,5,6}, lambda x: 1/6)
    for u in range(Rolls):
        Score1 = sum(random.choices(list(S1[1]), list(map(S1[2], range(len(S1[1])))), k=S1[0]))
        Score2 = sum(random.choices(list(S2[1]), list(map(S2[2], range(len(S2[1])))), k=S2[0]))
        if Score1 > Score2:
            Win = Win + 1
            Sentence = Win/100000*100
    print("the probability that player one wins is " + str(Sentence) + " percent.(Case 1)")

def Case2(Rolls):
    Win = 0
    S1 = (1, set(range(1, 36 + 1)), lambda x: 1 / 36)
    S2 = (36, {0, 1}, lambda x: 1 / 2)
    for u in range(Rolls):
        Score1 = sum(random.choices(list(S1[1]), list(map(S1[2], range(len(S1[1])))), k=S1[0]))
        Score2 = sum(random.choices(list(S2[1]), list(map(S2[2], range(len(S2[1])))), k=S2[0]))
        if Score1 > Score2:
                Win = Win + 1
                Sentence = Win / 100000 * 100
        print("the probability that player one wins is " + str(Sentence) + " percent.(Case 2)")
def Case3(Rolls):
    Win = 0
    S1 = (6, {1, 2, 3, 4}, lambda x: 1 / 4)
    S2 = (4, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, lambda x: 1 / 6)
    for u in range(Rolls):
        Score1 = sum(random.choices(list(S1[1]), list(map(S1[2], range(len(S1[1])))), k=S1[0]))
        Score2 = sum(random.choices(list(S2[1]), list(map(S2[2], range(len(S2[1])))), k=S2[0]))
        if Score1 > Score2:
            Win = Win + 1
            Sentence = Win / 100000 * 100
    print("the probability that player one wins is " + str(Sentence) + " percent.(Case 3)")
```

Does anyone have any idea how to combine these functions so they're more generalized?

made in Python 3.7

Comment: You could add `S1` and `S2` as function parameters, then you would have just one function that you call with different inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions are practically the same, only the `S1` and `S2` are different, you can pass them as arguments of the function. Also the output number of Case is different, so you can pass `case_num`.

```
def Case(Rolls,S1,S2,case_num):
    Win = 0
    for u in range(Rolls):
        Score1 = sum(random.choices(list(S1[1]), list(map(S1[2], range(len(S1[1])))), k=S1[0]))
        Score2 = sum(random.choices(list(S2[1]), list(map(S2[2], range(len(S2[1])))), k=S2[0]))
        if Score1 > Score2:
            Win = Win + 1
            Sentence = Win/100000*100
    print("the probability that player one wins is " + str(Sentence) + " percent.(Case "+case_num+")")

Case(somthing,(9, {1, 2, 3, 4}, lambda x: 1 / 4),(6, {1,2,3,4,5,6}, lambda x: 1/6),'1')
Case(somthing,(1, set(range(1, 36 + 1)), lambda x: 1 / 36),(36, {0, 1}, lambda x: 1 / 2),'2')
Case(somthing,(6, {1, 2, 3, 4}, lambda x: 1 / 4),(4, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, lambda x: 1 / 6),'3')
```